# create 3d surface graph without all the points

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have some (X, Y, Z) data points, for which I want to make a surface plot. X,Y,Z are integers. X ranges from 1 to 6, Y ranges from 1 to 6. I have Z data for all the (X,Y) points except (5,6) and (6,6). so I have to set Z = 0 for those two points. Is there a way that I don't plot the graph only for those two points, but plot the graph for all other points? Here is the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

v = [
    (1,1,1),
    (1,2,1),
    (1,3,1),
    (1,4,1),
    (1,5,1),
    (1,6,1),
    (2,1,2),
    (2,2,3),
    (2,3,4),
    (2,4,4),
    (2,5,5),
    (2,6,6),
    (3,1,3),
    (3,2,4),
    (3,3,4),
    (3,4,4),
    (3,5,4),
    (3,6,5),
    (4,1,4),
    (4,2,4),
    (4,3,4),
    (4,4,4),
    (4,5,5),
    (4,6,6),
    (5,1,5),
    (5,2,5),
    (5,3,5),
    (5,4,5),
    (5,5,6),
    (6,1,6),
    (6,2,5),
    (6,3,5),
    (6,4,5),
    (6,5,6),
]

def f(x, y):
    for xt,yt,z in v:
        if xt == x and yt == y:
            return z
    return 0


x = np.arange(1, 7, 1)
y = np.arange(1, 7, 1)

# X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
# print(X)
# print(Y)

X = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
]
X = np.array(X)

Y = [
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
    [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
    [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
    [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
    [6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6]
]
Y = np.array(Y)

Z = []
for yi in y:
    Z.append([])
    for xi in x:
        Z[yi-1].append(f(xi, yi))
Z = np.array(Z)

# print(Z)


ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap='viridis', edgecolor='none')
ax.set_title('surface')
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
plt.show()
```

Here is the plot I got:

[image]

I want to remove the 0's I have to put for points (5,6) and (6,6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the plot_surface method in matplotlib ignores masks (see [this open issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/487)), so you will need to use np.nan in place of the 0's for these particular Z values to not show up. This doesn't work perfectly, and may result in rendering artifacts like the colormap not working properly — but you can see that the surface plot displays except at the points (X,Y) = (5,6), (6,6).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

v = [
    (1,1,1),
    (1,2,1),
    (1,3,1),
    (1,4,1),
    (1,5,1),
    (1,6,1),
    (2,1,2),
    (2,2,3),
    (2,3,4),
    (2,4,4),
    (2,5,5),
    (2,6,6),
    (3,1,3),
    (3,2,4),
    (3,3,4),
    (3,4,4),
    (3,5,4),
    (3,6,5),
    (4,1,4),
    (4,2,4),
    (4,3,4),
    (4,4,4),
    (4,5,5),
    (4,6,6),
    (5,1,5),
    (5,2,5),
    (5,3,5),
    (5,4,5),
    (5,5,6),
    (6,1,6),
    (6,2,5),
    (6,3,5),
    (6,4,5),
    (6,5,6),
]

def f(x, y):
    for xt,yt,z in v:
        if xt == x and yt == y:
            return z
    return np.nan


x = np.arange(1, 7, 1)
y = np.arange(1, 7, 1)

# X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
# print(X)
# print(Y)

X = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
]
X = np.array(X)

Y = [
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
    [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
    [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
    [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
    [6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6]
]
Y = np.array(Y)

Z = []
for yi in y:
    Z.append([])
    for xi in x:
        Z[yi-1].append(f(xi, yi))
# Z = np.array(Z)
# prepare the masked array
Z = np.ma.array(Z)
Z_masked = np.ma.masked_where(Z == np.nan, Z)
# print(Z)


ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z_masked, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap='viridis', edgecolor='none')
ax.set_title('surface')
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: When I ran your code, it is showing nothing in the graph, no rendering is happening. and the program is giving this warning: code.py:89: UserWarning: Z contains NaN values. This may result in rendering artifacts.
  ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z_masked, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap='viridis', edgecolor='none')

Comment: I get the same warning, but the graph renders. What version of matplotlib are you using?

Comment: I am using matplotlib version: 3.2.1, numpy version: 1.18.4 on Linux Mint 19.3, python version: 3.6.9

Comment: maybe this is because of Linux OS. Thanks anyway for letting me know that it is not possible to do this.

Comment: Glad to have helped a bit! Perhaps seaborn or plotly would be able to create the surface plot with missing points